# How to construct a std::vector or a boost::array from a C array without copying?

Tags: c++, arrays, boost, stdvector

Given a pointer to an array of char, is it possible to construct a std::vector or boost::array from it, and avoiding memory copying?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You might be looking for the proposed `std::array_view`, or `string_view` since this is of `char`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because vectors own their own allocators and storage alike, there is no way (for non primitive elements construction from `move_iterator`s could help a bit).

So assuming the goal is to get a true `std::vector<char>&` for the existing storage, you'll never succeed, not even with custom allocators¹.

---

If you want a string, you can use `boost::string_ref` (in `utility/string_ref.hpp`).

Otherwise, you could use a 1-dimensional `multi_array_ref` (from Boost Multi Array)

#### 1. Using string_ref

This is definitely easiest:

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d10c1f7b9d0d6e31)</kbd>**

```
#include <boost/utility/string_ref.hpp>
#include <iostream>

using boost::string_ref;

int main() {
    char some_arr[] = "hello world";

    string_ref no_copy(some_arr);

    std::cout << no_copy;
}
```

#### 2. `multi_array_ref`

This is more versatile, and works "better" if you are not geared towards a string interface.

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/abca89f5dba918bb)</kbd>**

```
#include <boost/multi_array/multi_array_ref.hpp>
#include <iostream>

using ref = boost::multi_array_ref<char, 1>;
using boost::extents;

int main() {
    char some_arr[] = "hello world";

    ref no_copy(some_arr, extents[sizeof(some_arr)]);

    std::cout.write(no_copy.data(), no_copy.num_elements());
}
```

Both examples  print

```
hello world
```

---

¹ specializing `std::allocator<char>` is too evil to consider and probably outright prohibited by the standard

Comment: As a courtesy, here's the [live stream](https://www.livecoding.tv/video/string_ref-and-multi_array_ref-applied/) of me answering this question ([experiment](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/10?m=24182469#24182469))

Comment: @dyp I'd argue that there's no real value in using std::vector there then (the type will already be distinct due the custom allocator). But technically, that's a third option (depending on how narrowly you define `std::vector<T>` :))

Comment: @dyp Good luck passing that too `void api2::foo(std::vector<char> const&);` - that's why I said "I'd argue that there's no real value in using std::vector there". I think this is kind of the scenario the OP is facing. In fact, he should ask the library devs to fix the API to be less intrusive :)

Comment: @dyp I made this warning more explicit on your request.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative without using boost would be [std::reference_wrapper](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/reference_wrapper)

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

using namespace std;

struct S
{
    S() : val(0) {}
    S(int val_) : val(val_) {}
    S(const S& other) : val(other.val) {
        cout << "copy" << endl;
    }

    int val;
};


int main()
{
    char a[] = "Hello";
    vector<reference_wrapper<char>> v(a, a+5);

    S vS[] = {S(1), S(2), S(3)};

    vector<S> v_copy(vS, vS + 3);
    vector<reference_wrapper<S>> v_nocopy(vS, vS+3);
}
```

Using struct `S`you can see that objects are not copied to the vector. So this should work well also for `char`.

Comment: This is nice. It's important to realize that effectively you work on  a vector of `char*` now (from a memory viewpoint) and this could impact performance _very badly_. This is reason for me not to upvote it here, because I think the context is all about maximizing performance, by eliminating allocation/copying.

Comment: @sehe It sounds right. Just thought this was worth noting, at least for objects.